# I know what is the buoyancy force acting on a solid body but what is the buoyant force when the body is hollow?

Tags: buoyancy, fluid-statics

A empty cylindrical bucket when forced with its open end first into the water until its lower end is below the surface then what will be the buoyant force acting on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buoyant force will be almost the same as if it was a solid body (a little lower because the air inside is compressed a bit), because of Archimedes' principle.

Comment: Then should i consider the water displaced by the bucket  equal to buoyant force

Comment: Yes, that is Archimedes' principle.

Comment: What will be the total upward force acting on the bucket then .........

Comment: Well what would it be for a solid object?

Comment: In case of solid body it will be equal to wieght of volume displaced.......but according to me in case of bucket a conponent of force due the conpressed air must be added along with buoyant force

Comment: No, the total force upwards  is the buoyant force (as discussed) minus the gravitational force of the object.